# QGIS merge layers: error on data type

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, error

I am getting the following error:

[image]

The log is not providing lot of information.  **What is meant by data type?** I can't figure out where the problem is situated.

The layers I want to merge are all line-layers produced by the algorithm 'Polygons to lines'.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type for example "text" or "double". If layer A has attribute "attr_1" as text and layer B attribute "attr_1" as numeric then layers can't be merged. But there should be the real layer and attribute names between the curly brackets and you may have some other issue.

Comment: You both pointed me in the right direction, now I can make a workaround.  If you post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In QGIS each attribute field has a fixed data type. Common data types are integer number and text but there are more. If field is defined as an integer you cannot store free text strings into it. You can see the full list of data types which are supported by QGIS if you open a layer for editing and start adding a new field.

[image]

The error you got can for example mean that two layers to be merged both have an attribute named "CODE" but in one table it is defined to be text while in another table it is an integer number. In that case the layers cannot be merged. A workaround is to rename the fields into "CODE_INT" and "CODE_TEXT". Then the new merged layer will include both attributes as separate fields.

Comment: Do you mean attributes which I can find under right click on the layer -> Open Attributes Table? In that case I don't have duplicate names there, but still can't merge.

Comment: That's what I mean. But the error message is a bit strange, {} are placeholders and actually there should be an understandable layer name and field name in the error message. Could you add a list of attributes and their datatypes into your question?

Comment: That's what I thought about those placeholders, actually I just filled a bug report about that.
I'm not the OP :) Besides, I already managed to do what I want by just copying shapes. But if you want, I can put them here in comment (or we can set up a chat) and show you them - thought you can really believe me that they are different :)